# Door handle fell off — and we can’t find a replacement screw

Tags: doors, doorknob

Our door handle fell off — the screw keeping it on the handle fell out, and we couldn’t find it anywhere. We’ve tried every possible screw at Lowe’s, but I guess this is special/proprietary in some way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 29):

The screw is still there:
<sub>Your original pic:</sub>
[image]

<sub>Enhanced for clarity:</sub>
[image]

You need to find a small Allen Wrench which fits the socket in the end of this grub screw.
Slide the door handle back on, then use the Allen-Wrench to back the screw out 1 or 2 turns so that it grips into the hole in the door handle.

What probably happened is that this screw was turned in a little more than necessary when the handle was installed, and now over time the 'pipe' part of the door handle which slides over the 'shaft' of the latch mechanism has worn or expanded slightly - just enough that the end of the screw still sticking out of the shaft no longer grips in the hole in the side of the 'pipe'.
If the screw feels loose when you turn it, then it would probably be a good idea to use a drop of thread locker to make sure the screw doesn't wiggle out in future.

Comment: Or get a longer set screw.

Comment: "a drop of thread locker" - but not a strong one; Loctite 222 (purple) would work. Otherwise, the hex socket may well round out before you can remove it.

Comment: Anyway, it's almost certainly not proprietary. All of the modern locks that I know of sold in Chile, where I live, use metric thread (m4-m6) for these set bolts.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but I cannot see the black grub screw in the black hole in that photo (even after adjusting the levels in Photoshop). So now I am dying to hear back from the OP whether it is turns out it is actually in there, despite the low stakes.

Comment: Your patience in explaining this is commendable.

Comment: @Oddthinking the "hole" IS the grub screw. Look slightly farther out instead to see the actual hole.

Comment: I agree. Fiddle with contrast and brightness and I believe you can see the hex recess. OP (Jenn): it appears to be an Allen-type screw with a hex recess (rather than slot or cross) which you're mistaking for a hole. It's fairly common to find this used where a tight connection is required.

Comment: @fectin (and Mark): Ohhhhhhh! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

They are normally set screws (grub screws), without a visible head.  If you have another door handle, then remove the screw from there to find a replacement.